# Freelancer in Germany, South African client, do I charge VAT?

Tags: germany, vat

I am working as a freelance software developer in Germany, and I need to know if I should be charging a South African client VAT or not. I have found out the answer for Germany, other EU states, USA and Australia, but does anyone know specifically for South Africa?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m curious – what is the case for charging VAT to the countries you know about, like Australia and US?

Comment: No, there is no case - from what I read you should not charge VAT to those countries, if invoicing from an EU country...I assumed South Africa would be the same but could not find specific info confirming it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I work with some clients in Vietnam, and my accountant advised that for that country I do need to collect VAT (I am based in Germany). So it seems to be something related to tax treaties or something like that.

Comment: As far as I know, for an invoicer in the EU, the rule is to charge VAT to a local invoicee, reverse VAT for a EU invoicee and no VAT outside EU.

Answer (score 2):

In Denmark, the answer would be no for all those countries.

However, when submitting the quarterly/semi-annual VAT to the authorities, one must also register the amount of non-VAT sales (EU and non-EU).

Comment: Thank you - to your knowledge should the same rules apply for all EU states (i.e., the same would likely be true in Germany)?

Comment: @JosephCLawrence: I would imagine so, but am not an accountant - merely a one-man freelance shop having billed clients in Sweden and the UK